# HTML/Text Spacing Problem

Tags: html, css, spacing

[HTML Spacing Problems http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/705/ohdear.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/705/ohdear.png)

As you can see from the image above, I'm having a few problems.

[The Image, if the above won't load](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/705/ohdear.png)

I'm using CSS to keep everything in place... do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: I see a number of issues there. Can you be more specific?

Comment: you'll need to provide the code you're using

Comment: images are nice, but we're programmers. we need to see the markup and the css. :)

Comment: Is the problem how the text in the image looks, or is the problem what the text says?

Comment: I can't really product code, since it's dynamically produced, all I can say is that data is presented from a WYSIWYG editor into DB and from DB to page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing what your questions are based on what I see in that image...

It looks like you have 2 ordered lists inside a fieldset.

It looks like your first problem is that your ordered lists have no left margin style, so the numbers for the list "pop out" of the fieldset. To fix that, just add some margin to your ordered lists:

```
ol {
    margin-left: 20px; /* experiment with the 
                          left width until you're 
                          happy with the spacing */
}
```

Your second issue looks like you have no margin on the top or bottom of your lists, so they stack up right on top of each other. This should be easily fixed with the following style rules (which includes the margin rule defined above):

```
ol {
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
    /* again, experiment with the margin size until you're happy with it */
}
```

That's the best I can do without seeing the markup or styles you have.

Comment: That sorted out the problem and it's back in the fieldset, but, those large gaps between the lists are still there :(

Comment: With this: margin: 2px 0px 2px 20px;

Comment: The first and third set of units in your margin rule are for the top and bottom margin. Make the size larger than 2 pixels and it should fix that.